# Missing data in columns error during tidymodels classification with cvfolds

Tags: r, tidymodels

So I set up my intitial splitting of the data and create a recipe. All the columns except for the role and outcome column are numeric

```
data_split <- initial_split(my_table_of_stuff, 
                            strata = predict_path)

train_data <- training(data_split) 
test_data <- testing(data_split)

set.seed(100)

cv_folds <-
    vfold_cv(train_data, 
             v = 5, 
             strata = predict_path) 

my_recip <- recipe(predict_path ~ ., data = train_data) %>%
    update_role(sample_id, new_role = "ID") %>% 
    update_role(pathology, new_role = "ID") %>% 
    update_role(disease, new_role = "ID")  %>% 
    update_role(tissue_clean, new_role = "ID")  %>% 
    update_role(mutations, new_role = "ID")  %>% 
    step_zv(all_numeric(), -all_outcomes()) %>%
    step_normalize(all_numeric(), -all_outcomes())
```

My specification for classification and the worflow

```
rf_spec <- 
    rand_forest() %>% 
    set_engine("ranger", importance = "impurity") %>% 
    set_mode("classification")

rf_wflow <-
    workflow() %>%
    add_recipe(my_recip) %>% 
    add_model(rf_spec)
```

And then finally running the model on the cross-validation folds gets me

```
rf_res <-
    rf_wflow %>% 
    fit_resamples(
        resamples = cv_folds, 
        metrics = metric_set(
            recall, precision, f_meas, 
            accuracy, kap,
            roc_auc, sens, spec),
        control = control_resamples(save_pred = TRUE)
    ) 

Error in `estimate_tune_results()`:
! All of the models failed. See the .notes column.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
Warning message:
All models failed. Run `show_notes(.Last.tune.result)` for more information.
```

with a missing data error across the models

```
unique notes:
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Error: Missing data in columns: LRP8_1, DNAJC12_2, DNAJC12_1, KCNIP2_1, KNDC1_2, ...
```

I'm not coding for any categorical values here, but I am removing any zero variance variables, so, maybe that's it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting an error because the variables `LRP8_1, DNAJC12_2, DNAJC12_1, KCNIP2_1, KNDC1_2, ...` contain one of more missing values, which the `ranger` model doesn't support.

I like to use the [skimr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/skimr/vignettes/skimr.html) package to find what variables contain missing values.

Without being able to see what kind of data you have I can't advice how to deal with it, but {recipes} does have [several steps that performs imputation](https://recipes.tidymodels.org/reference/index.html#step-functions-imputation).

Below is your reprex with fake data. Notice how it errors about `num4` and `num5` since they have missing values in them.

```r
library(tidymodels)

my_table_of_stuff <- tibble(
  predict_path = factor(sample(1:2, 100, TRUE)),
  sample_id = sample(letters, 100, TRUE),
  pathology = sample(letters, 100, TRUE),
  disease = sample(letters, 100, TRUE),
  tissue_clean = sample(letters, 100, TRUE),
  mutations = sample(letters, 100, TRUE),
  num1 = rnorm(100),
  num2 = rnorm(100),
  num3 = rnorm(100),
  num4 = c(rnorm(99), NA),
  num5 = c(rnorm(99), NA)
)

data_split <- initial_split(my_table_of_stuff, 
                            strata = predict_path)

train_data <- training(data_split) 
test_data <- testing(data_split)

set.seed(100)

cv_folds <-
  vfold_cv(train_data, 
           v = 5, 
           strata = predict_path) 

my_recip <- recipe(predict_path ~ ., data = train_data) %>%
  update_role(sample_id, new_role = "ID") %>% 
  update_role(pathology, new_role = "ID") %>% 
  update_role(disease, new_role = "ID")  %>% 
  update_role(tissue_clean, new_role = "ID")  %>% 
  update_role(mutations, new_role = "ID")  %>% 
  step_zv(all_numeric(), -all_outcomes()) %>%
  step_normalize(all_numeric(), -all_outcomes())

rf_spec <- 
  rand_forest() %>% 
  set_engine("ranger", importance = "impurity") %>% 
  set_mode("classification")

rf_wflow <-
  workflow() %>%
  add_recipe(my_recip) %>% 
  add_model(rf_spec) 

rf_res <-
  rf_wflow %>% 
  fit_resamples(
    resamples = cv_folds, 
    metrics = metric_set(
      recall, precision, f_meas, 
      accuracy, kap,
      roc_auc, sens, spec),
    control = control_resamples(save_pred = TRUE)
  ) 
#> x Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/1: Error: Missing data in columns: num4, num5.
#> x Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/1: Error: Missing data in columns: num4, num5.
#> x Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/1: Error: Missing data in columns: num4, num5.
#> x Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/1 (predictions): Error: Missing data in columns: num4, num5.
#> x Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/1: Error: Missing data in columns: num4, num5.
#> Warning: All models failed. Run `show_notes(.Last.tune.result)` for more
#> information.
```

Below I have taken the same code and data, and added `step_impute_mean()` at the end of the recipe. And it now runs clean. Notice how I am able to use `all_numeric_predictors()` instead of `all_nuemric(), -all_outcomes()`.

```r
library(tidymodels)

my_table_of_stuff <- tibble(
  predict_path = factor(sample(1:2, 100, TRUE)),
  sample_id = sample(letters, 100, TRUE),
  pathology = sample(letters, 100, TRUE),
  disease = sample(letters, 100, TRUE),
  tissue_clean = sample(letters, 100, TRUE),
  mutations = sample(letters, 100, TRUE),
  num1 = rnorm(100),
  num2 = rnorm(100),
  num3 = rnorm(100),
  num4 = c(rnorm(99), NA),
  num5 = c(rnorm(99), NA)
)

data_split <- initial_split(my_table_of_stuff, 
                            strata = predict_path)

train_data <- training(data_split) 
test_data <- testing(data_split)

set.seed(100)

cv_folds <-
  vfold_cv(train_data, 
           v = 5, 
           strata = predict_path) 

my_recip <- recipe(predict_path ~ ., data = train_data) %>%
  update_role(sample_id, new_role = "ID") %>% 
  update_role(pathology, new_role = "ID") %>% 
  update_role(disease, new_role = "ID")  %>% 
  update_role(tissue_clean, new_role = "ID")  %>% 
  update_role(mutations, new_role = "ID")  %>% 
  step_zv(all_numeric_predictors()) %>%
  step_normalize(all_numeric_predictors()) %>%
  step_impute_mean(all_numeric_predictors())

rf_spec <- 
  rand_forest() %>% 
  set_engine("ranger", importance = "impurity") %>% 
  set_mode("classification")

rf_wflow <-
  workflow() %>%
  add_recipe(my_recip) %>% 
  add_model(rf_spec) 

rf_res <-
  rf_wflow %>% 
  fit_resamples(
    resamples = cv_folds, 
    metrics = metric_set(
      recall, precision, f_meas, 
      accuracy, kap,
      roc_auc, sens, spec),
    control = control_resamples(save_pred = TRUE)
  ) 

rf_res
#> # Resampling results
#> # 5-fold cross-validation using stratification 
#> # A tibble: 5 × 5
#>   splits          id    .metrics         .notes           .predictions     
#>   <list>          <chr> <list>           <list>           <list>           
#> 1 <split [59/15]> Fold1 <tibble [8 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 3]> <tibble [15 × 6]>
#> 2 <split [59/15]> Fold2 <tibble [8 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 3]> <tibble [15 × 6]>
#> 3 <split [59/15]> Fold3 <tibble [8 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 3]> <tibble [15 × 6]>
#> 4 <split [59/15]> Fold4 <tibble [8 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 3]> <tibble [15 × 6]>
#> 5 <split [60/14]> Fold5 <tibble [8 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 3]> <tibble [14 × 6]>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! I "knew" there weren't any NA values in the dataset so I didn't even think to check this in advance - lol